# Desktop/Screen Sharing in Flash (With/without FMS)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, adobe, flash-builder

Does anyone have any idea about the screen sharing in flash. i have to implement it and have no idea about it.

Please share your ideas.

Comment: @Vipual: Please avoid using Signature while you posting an Question mate

Comment: is there any reason to avoid signature ??

Comment: @Vipual: Please read the FAQ of this site, there you can find this instructions mate

Comment: ok, and its Vipul not vipual :)

Comment: I m sorry for misspelled your name, Mr.Vipul

Comment: +1 @Vipul_11088 "i have to implement it and have no idea about it."

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `wowza media server` for desktop/screen sharing. There are lot sample availble in their site.

Comment: thanks Raja for your feedback, but i need any library/api to implement it, and that media server is paid, can you please suggest me another ??